# WordPress Error after update

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating my WordPress website I received the following error message whenever I attempt to login to the admin area.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_object_page() (previously declared in /home/nichea5/mausmedia.net/mm1/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:1101) in /home/nichea5/mausmedia.net/mm1/wp-admin/includes/deprecated.php on line 1342

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have updated `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` both to latest version ?

Comment: Delete /wp-admin/ and /wp-includes/ directories and upload them again via FTP. Looks like some files were corrupted during the update.

Comment: I replaced both wp-includes and wp-admin with those from a fresh copy of WordPress and it worked. Thanks again for the help.